# How to show my custom Drawable in activity layout on Android

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to display 2 (and more) squares on main activity and show a message when clicked on one of them with the the number of the square. My problem is that only the first square gets displayed (There's only one blue square on the screen and nothing more).

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blank);

    final LinearLayout mContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.blank);

    View sq1 = new MyView(this, 0, 100, 100, Color.BLUE);
    View sq2 = new MyView(this, 1, 200, 200, Color.GREEN);

    mContainer.addView(sq1,0);
    mContainer.addView(sq2,1);
}}
```

Drawable class

```
public class MyView extends View implements OnClickListener{
private final Context context;
private final int index;
private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

public MyView(Context context, int index, int xPos, int yPos, int color) {
    super(context);

    this.index = index;
    this.context = context;
    setOnClickListener(this);

    int x = xPos;
    int y = yPos;
    int width = xPos;
    int height = yPos;

    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(context, index+1+". view clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

blank.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/blank">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @iturki [screen](http://imgur.com/6bN8SUJ)

Comment: Write custom adapter for this type of UI.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed two things in your example:

Firstly: You have to set LayoutParams to your views.

```
LayoutParams paramsSq1 = new LayoutParams(100,100);
LayoutParams paramsSq2 = new LayoutParams(200,200);

View sq1 = new MyView(this, 0, 100, 100, Color.BLUE);
sq1.setLayoutParams(paramsSq1);


View sq2 = new MyView(this, 1, 200, 200, Color.GREEN);
sq2.setLayoutParams(paramsSq2);

mContainer.addView(sq1, 0);
mContainer.addView(sq2, 1);
```

Secondly: Draw your shapes from the origin point (0,0).

```
  public MyView(Context context, int index, int xPos, int yPos, int color) {
    super(context);

    this.index = index;
    this.context = context;
    setOnClickListener(this);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = xPos;
    int height = yPos;

    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the `LayoutParams` for the `LinearLayout`'s children.

Try this:

```
LinearLayout mContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blank);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

mContainer.addView(sq1, params);
mContainer.addView(sq2, params);
```